# How can I paginate results from get_children

Tags: pagination, media-library

I followed this method of [getting images from the media library](http://johnford.is/programmatically-pull-attachments-from-wordpress-posts//).

```
// get the first image attached to the current post
function aldenta_get_post_image($size = 'thumbnail') {
    global $post;

    $photos = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') );

    if ($photos) {
        $photo = array_shift($photos);
        return wp_get_attachment_image($photo->ID, $size);
    }

    return false;
}
```

But I want to paginate the results, how can I do that?

Comment: Paginate it based on what? A set query var? A value passed into the function?

Comment: @t31os, currently, if there are 100 images, it will show them all, I want to limit the results to something like 20 maybe? so that the user wont see 100s of images at once

Comment: Did you post the wrong function then, the above function looks like it would only give a single result. Also, you unfortunately didn't answer my question(see previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `'offset'` parameter like in [`get_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts). You can take the number of the page you're on as value.

Comment: This assumes your page is $paged. How do you break up a get_children query (or get_posts) to be paged?

Comment: The same way. You have the current page number stored somewhere. Otherwise the code is broken already.

Comment: 'posts_per_page' does not work in get_pages, like it does in wp_query. You can limit the query, but not the display.

Answer (score 0):

`get_children()` returns an array of posts, not a query that can be looped through and therefore paginated.

I would encourage you to use WP_Query instead. [This WPSE answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15174/9844) should provide a code snippet to get you started. Then it should just be a matter of [looping through the query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query) and using standard WP paging.

Comment: Downside to WP_Query is that there is no hierarchical argument. You can only get children 1 layer deep.