# Broken? WP_Query and "attachment" as a post type

Tags: wp-query, attachments

I have a gallery attached to a page. On that page, I'm running the following query:

```
$events_gallery = new WP_Query( // Start a new query for our videos
array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, // Get data from the current post
    'post_type' => 'attachment', // Only bring back attachments
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', // Only bring back attachments that are images
    'posts_per_page' => '3', // Show us the first three results
    'status' => 'inherit', // Inherit the status of the parent post 
    'orderby' => 'rand', // Order the attachments randomly  
    )
);
```

I've experimented quite a few ways and, for some reason, I can't get attachments to return. Am I missing something obvious here?

**Update***

Thanks to Wok for pointing me in the right direction.

It turns out I was using "status" instead of "post_status". The codex had used "status" as the example in its in-context explanation of the "attachment" post type. I updated the codex to reference "post_status" instead. The correct code is as follows:

```
$events_gallery = new WP_Query( // Start a new query for our videos
array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, // Get data from the current post
    'post_type' => 'attachment', // Only bring back attachments
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', // Only bring back attachments that are images
    'posts_per_page' => '3', // Show us the first three results
    'post_status' => 'inherit', // Attachments default to "inherit", rather than published. Use "inherit" or "any".
    'orderby' => 'rand', // Order the attachments randomly  
    )
);
```

Comment: I wonder what the difference is between post_status being set to 'null' vs 'inherit''

Comment: You just saved me a lot of pain with `'post_status' => 'inherit'`  Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These are the query parameters i use...works for me when i loop through the results

```
array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'post_type'=> 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/jpg,image/png'                  
);
```

For more detail, please see official documentation for WP_Query's [status parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#status-parameters)

Answer (score 20):

Add in `$args`, it is important.

```
'post_status' => 'any'
```

**Do not:** `'post_status' => null`

This is important because attachments don't have a `post_status`, so the default value for `post_status`, `published`, will find no attachments.

Comment: Please make an effort to explain the answer, rather than just post a line or two of code.

Comment: Yes, how come this works?  I couldn't get my attachment to show up in my archive page until I added this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the query it generates, it does appear to be a bug of sorts. 'status' => 'inherit' is interpreted as the parent's status, when the entry in the db for the attachment is literally 'inherit'.

An alternative is to use get_children in place of WP_Query.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to display all images that are attachments to a post using this code.

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ,'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID );
$attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) { ?>
      <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID , false ); ?>" />
<?php   }
    } ?>
```

And to echo the URL of the original full size image, you could link that image off to

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID , false ); ?>
```

Hopefully this is an approach to what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does the pagination work with that? And can you show the rest of your output code? I'm in the middle of re-coding a themes gallery to actually paginate the attachments that are on the page. Thanks!

Comment: If I upload 4 images to a post, and I add this into the main content entry div in single.php, it will just spit out 4 image tags. The src= of each will lead to the original large image size.

Pagination does not work with this, as it spits out any and all images that are attached to the post.